# Storing Private Files on Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, apple-push-notifications

I have a scenario here related to storing private files on heroku.

I need to store private files( certificates and keys for sending push notifications to IOS devices) in a heroku app(uses Cedar stack), I can push these files to heroku server through git but storing on git is not secure as these are private. So, I want to secure copy (SCP) these files to heroku server but heroku doesnt allow incoming connections and storing these files on S3 bucket is not a great solution as it takes some time to get the file from S3 bucket which increases the delay in sending each push notification when in a loop.

I'm kinda lost finding the right solution to this scenario. The gem https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup accepts the private files either as a file object or a string (that points out the path of the files on server). Heroku allows to set config vars(only strings) that can be used in Environment but not files.

Could someone please suggest me some workarounds in this scenario, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the file system in Heroku, hence you need a different storage system.

You can either use a cloud-system storage such as Amazon S3, and encrypt the connection and the data transferred to ensure the information stay private. The delay can be minimized using a memory-based cache system, such as memcached.

Another approach is to store the data in the database, as binary information. You can either use the same application database, or a database specifically designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using some external storage services as you can't store files on Heroku.

[Using AWS S3 to Store Static Assets and File Uploads](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)